# problem with Object given by switcher in python

Tags: python, class, object, switch-statement

I seem to have a problem with a switch-fashioned code when I try to create an object where its class depends on an input.

Let us say there are two classes, Class1 and Class2. Both of them, when I create an object, give me a message "Object of Class<1 or 2> created"
Then there is this new class which have a method that take a string when I create the object. this string is "Class1" or "Class2".

Here the tricky part: based on this string I create an object Class1 or an object Class2 as follows:

```
def type_to_object(self, type):
        switcher = {
            "Class1": Class1(),
            "Class2": Class2(),
        }
        return switcher.get(type, "Invalid Class")
```

Now, this worked well in similar cases. The problem here is that it seems to create both the objects, even if I only got one in return when I call the method (obviously). I say this because refering to what I said above, I get both the messages  "Object of Class1 created" and  "Object of Class2 created"

Thank you in advance

PS: what it seems super strange, is that it should not enter all the cases, only the one equal to type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create instances of both your classes in the switcher dictionary.

Try this instead:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.who_am_i = "Class1"


class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.who_am_i = "Class2"


def type_to_object(class_type):
    switcher = {
        "Class1": Class1,  # No parentheses here, we don't want an instance. Just a type
        "Class2": Class2,  #
    }
    selected_class = switcher.get(class_type, None)
    if selected_class is None:
        raise RuntimeError("Invalid Class")
    return selected_class()  # Now, we use parentheses: we want to create an instance


c = type_to_object("Class1")
print(c.who_am_i)
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right! just a small thing. maybe it is because I'm used to other languages, but why in the switcher it goes "after" the column? shouln't it create just the object of the case selected ?